# Sinch voice call stop working suddenly

Tags: android, sinch, android-sinch-api

I have integrated sinch sdk with my application after test sample push app

It was working very nice untill today 5 pm

It is now 8 pm and I am facing the following problem

Testing devices (note5 , note4 and J5)

I can hear the voice only in note5 but could not hear anything in note4 or J5

It was working 4 hours ago with note4 and J5 and now it is not

I only change in UI and add features for speaker on/off and microphone on/off

Can you help please as soon as you can?

Comment: Can you share you asnwer code and maybe logcat if you implement onLogMessage

Comment: same problem. It was working before but not working now. I am testing it on Samsung galaxy J5. Any suggestion @Amira ?